# setInterval function runs indefinitely even after each Interval is THREE_MONTHS

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, setinterval, prisma

I have to delete all the `OTP` records which expired after every `three months`.

In `/sheduled-tasks/OTPRecords.js`

```js
const prisma = require("../services/prisma");

const THREE_MONTHS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 90;

async function deleteExpiredOTPRecords() {
    console.log("first");
    setInterval(async () => {
      console.log("INTERVAL", THREE_MONTHS);
      const today = new Date();
      const yesterday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1));
      const records = await prisma.otp.deleteMany({
        where: { expires_at: { lte: yesterday } },
      });
      console.log(records);
    }, THREE_MONTHS);
}
module.exports = deleteExpiredOTPRecords;
```

In `/index.js`

```js
 deleteExpiredOTPRecords();
```

I was expecting this function run after every `THREE_MONTHS` but my code runs indefinitely in a loop, i am unable to figure out where am i going wrong.

### OUTPUT

```js
INTERVAL 7776000000
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
INTERVAL 7776000000
INTERVAL 7776000000
{ count: 0 }
^C(node:33075) [DEP0164] DeprecationWarning: Implicit coercion to integer for exit code is 
deprecated.
```

Comment: I am not clear on the logic of this. Why attempt to wait for three months - how would records created the day after the previous three months be caught at the right time? And is this JS really running uninterrupted forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval is stored in a signed 32-bit int.so what happens here is if the mili-second value is greater than `2^31-1` which is `2147483647` the interval becomes invalid hence infinite loop.

check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#return_value)

> So your value is 7776000000 is greater than 4294967295 (2**31 - 1).

Comment: Is there a solution to it @Shankaja Aroshana

Comment: you need to setup CRON job every 3 month in the backend.

Comment: Yes, cron may work but, is there a way around to overcome the max value limitation of `setInterval`

Comment: No it's how js works .